# How to regularize loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm learning tensorflow and I'm having some trouble understanding how to regularize the cost function. I've looked and I'm finding a lot of different answers. Could someone please tell me how to regularize the cost function?

I took Andrew Ng's machine learning course on Coursera, and there is one thing that seems to be different when I look on forums. It seems like most people regularize each weight as well as regularizing the final cost function, and on the course there is no mention of that. Which one is correct?

Comment: Do you have some code sample you're working on?

Comment: @Sharky I'm mainly just trying to learn the language. I have a script, but it has other bugs and I primarily just use it to test new commands. I just want to know how to add the l2 regularization term to a network.

Comment: Are you using Estimator, or keras?

Comment: @Sharky I’m using ordinary tensorflow. I’ve heard of estimator, but never really looked into what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `TensorFlow`L2 (Tikhonov) regularization with regularization parameter `lambda_`could be written like this:

```
# Assuming you defined a graph, placeholders and logits layer.
# Using cross entropy loss:
lambda_ = 0.1
xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=logits)
ys = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
l2_norms = [tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
l2_norm = tf.reduce_sum(l2_norms)
cost = ys + lambda_*l2_norm
# from here, define optimizer, train operation and train ... :-)
```

Comment: But why not just add the l2 regularization term to the cost at the end, rather than adding it to each weight and summing the regularizations?

Comment: And what is the difference here between tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()? Also, shouldn’t it be tf.reduce_mean()?

Comment: `But why not just add the l2 regularization term to the cost at the end, rather than adding it to each weight and summing the regularizations? ` - It is added to the cost at the end: `cost = ys + lambda_*l2_norm`

Comment: `Also, shouldn’t it be tf.reduce_mean()?` - No, it should be `reduce_sum` since we're summing squared parameters.

Comment: `And what is the difference here between tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()?` - Probably it is for implementing the same regularization by adding each l2-norm of each variable to the collection `GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` while constructing a graph. And later to access those variables you call this function. In my answer I do not add variables to collection but access them using `tf.trainable_variables()` and only then compute l2-norm.

Comment: @Vlad can you please assist me with the similar query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432963/l2-norm-regularized-custom-loss-function-in-keras-with-tensor-flow-as-backend

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just define regularizer function inside desired layer.

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters,
                       kernel_size,
                       strides=strides,
                       padding=padding,
                       ...
                       kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2()
                       )
```

With Estimator API or low level tensorflow you sum all regularizers to your loss value. You can get it with `tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()` and either just add it to loss or use `tf.losses.get_total_loss()` Keras will handle it internally.