# SGD with weight decay parameter in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, deep-learning

In Keras and Pytorch, the SGD optimizer have Weight Decay parameter.I found **tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer** do not have weight decay parameter. What is the tensorflow equivalent of SGD with weight decay?

Pytorch Optim - https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html

Keras Optimizer - https://keras.io/optimizers/

Comment: If by weight decay you mean L2 regularization, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029716/how-to-regularize-loss-function/55031508#55031508)

Answer (score 1):

One way to get weight decay in TensorFlow is by adding L2-regularization to the loss. This is equivalent to weight decay for standard SGD (but not for adaptive gradient optimizers) according to [Decoupled Weight Decay Regularization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05101.pdf) paper by Loshchilov & Hutter.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is an implementation of decoupled weight decay in the `tensorflow-addons` package. See

   https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/SGDW
2. `pytorch.optim`'s `weight_decay` is L2-regularization, it can get the same result but the value of the `weight_decay` param is different.

   To have use the same behavior from pytorch in tensorflow add L2 regularization. One way to to do this, if your layer is dense:

   ```py
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(
      num_classes,
      activation=dont_care,
      kernel_initializer=dont_care,
      kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(L2_WEIGHT_DECAY),
      bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(L2_WEIGHT_DECAY))
   ```