# Regularized Custom Loss Function in Keras with Tensor flow as Backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function, regularized

Instead of layer level regulaization that can be implemented in Keras directly, I want to implement following custom loss function in keras without adding regularizer in layers.

```
Custom Loss=‖I-P‖_2+γ‖∂I‖_2
```

where I is the true and P is the Predicted output of network, γ is a prior or regularization constant and ∂I is a true input gradient as prior function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `∂I`? The derivative of `y_true`? How do you define it?

Comment: @Vlad Thats true, I is the true image, P is the predicted image and ∂I is the gradient of the true image.

Comment: So you want Jacobian. The derivative with respect to what?

Comment: @Vlad the gradient of an image with respect to x and y direction. ∂I is basically the magnitude of conventional image gradient.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient

Comment: @Vlad any valuable suggestion please for the said query?